# Is there a better way to serde serialize a struct defined in different crate?

Tags: rust, serde

I am looking for alternative solutions to this problem...  A sample project that shows this issue: https://storage.googleapis.com/abitofhelp_public_share/serdebin.zip

I have a domain crate that contains a Project struct.
The domain crate must not include external dependencies, such as serde.

When I wrap the Project inside a struct, ProjectDto, in a different, dependent crate and add serialization tags, the compiler reports that the Serialize trait has not been
satisfied for the Project field in the ProjectDto.

Is there a way to make this work without adding the external dependency to the domain crate?

I can only think of copying the project.rs file from the domain crate and pasting it into the crate that needs to do the serialization.  I can add serde's tags to it. I can create a mapper that maps between the Projects in both places in case they diverge.

Here is the error that is reported by the compiler:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Project: Serialize` is not satisfied
    --> src/project_dto.rs:6:39
    |
6   | #[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Serialize, Deserialize)]
    |                                       ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Serialize` is not
    |                                                 implemented for `Project`
7   | pub struct ProjectDto {
8   |     pub project: Project,
    |     --- required by a bound introduced by this call
```

Thank you for your time and interest,
Mike

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Do not include links to download zipped source code.

Comment: In general doing what you described is very hard due to rust's _orphan rule_.

Comment: serde has a [mechanism](https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html) that can "trick" the compiler, but I would recommend against using it, especially if you are controlling both crates.

Comment: I would recommend adding `serde` as a dependency of your `domain` crate. If you don't want to "bloat" your crate and only include it when the consumer of your crate really needs it, you can hide implementation behind a [feature gate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html) which is a very popular thing to do in the rust ecosystem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Aleksander.  I am working on a proof-of-concept project for my boss, who wants to see a clean-architecture for one of our projects.  The domain must only contain structs with no external dependencies. In this architecture, another crate/layer adapts requests to models and vice-versa, which requires serde. 

I like your idea of using a feature gate...  I don't have a serious objection to having two Project entities, as I've described.  They are in different crates/layers, so it wouldn't be too confusing, but I was hoping for a better option.  :)

Comment: I found the following solution that serde provides.  I am going to give it a whirl tomorrow and will report back.  https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html

Comment: @A Bit of Help this is exactly what I have linked in my third comment. :) I advised against using it, because that will mean that you have to keep both structs in different crates in sync.

Comment: "In this architecture, another crate/layer adapts requests to models and vice-versa" is this your only reason for using a separate crate? If you don't have multiple consumers of those data models (that is multiple _crates_ use them as their dependency), and don't have a substantial reduce in build times due to crate split I would argue that separate crate will make you more problems than good. If you want to have a "clean" model you can just stuck those structs in a different module inside the same crate.

Comment: @ABitofHelp note that, in Rust, contrary to number of other programming languages, the philosophy is to avoid putting too many things in the standard library and instead rely on crates. `serde` is an example of a crate that is maintained, AFAIK, by a part of the Rust team, and is considered central in Rust's ecosystem. My point is that while it can make sense to try to avoid dependencies in other languages, in Rust it's much more questionable, especially for `serde` which could almost be thought of as part of the std. I hope this can help you convince your boss it's ok to depend on `serde`.

Comment: Thank you @jthulhu and @"Aleksander Krauze"  for your comments and ideas.  I agree that it is better to maintain a single object than two and not to try workarounds for orphaning (aka "serde remote").  I posted this question in rust's community forum and Tristan provided a solution similar to Aleksander's, which I am going to use.  It is a good balance and I think that I can argue well for it with my boss. :P.  Jthulhu makes a great point about serde practically being part of Rust's std library, too.  Thank you, all, for your help!

Comment: Here is the link to Tristan's comments: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/is-there-a-better-way-to-serde-serialize-a-struct-defined-in-different-crate/98818/5

The crux of the solution is to use a feature in the domain crate to include serde's serialization.  So, the domain can be used "clean" and may be used with serialization.  kewl beans!